# Using a class as a template parameter for a templated class with forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates

I know that after a forward declaration such as

```
class Foo;
```

I can declare a variable as `Foo*` or `Foo&`, but not `Foo`.

If I have a templated class and instantiation

```
template<class T>
class Bar {
  public:
    T baz;
};
...
Bar<Foo> v;
```

how would the above rule apply? Would Foo have to have been fully declared (as opposed to only forward declared) at the point the class `Bar` is defined, or at the point `v` is declared? Or maybe it only has to be at one point that `Bar<Foo>` is used anywhere in the source files, and all the others it is not? Something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Bar<Foo>` requires the full `Foo` definition because it contains a data member of type `Foo`. You could not forward declare in this case. In this respect, `Bar<Foo>` is the equivalent of

```
class BarFoo 
{  
 public:
    Foo baz;
};
```

Comment: But where is it required? Only at the `Bar<Foo>` usage, or is it retroactively at the definition of `Bar<T>`?

Comment: @baruch only when you instantiate the type `Bar<Foo>`. The class template `Bar` knows nothing about `Foo`. Otherwise templates would not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you just have to mentally replace `T` with the template argument type:

```
template<class T>
class Bar {
public:
    T baz;
};
```

With this method, the above code will change to:

```
class Bar {
public:
    Foo baz;
};
```

Now, as you know, the compiler will need the full declaration of `Foo` in order to know how much size to allocate when declaring a `Bar` object.

Comment: Yes, but the question was where this replacement takes place, and so where the full deceleration of `Foo` has to be known: At first instantiation, at each one, or retroactively at the `Bar` definition?

Comment: @baruch, when you use `Bar<Foo>`.